# How to test the functionality of clicking away from a dropdown menu, and it closing

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I am testing the functionality of a dropdown window in cypress. Once the dropdown menu is open and tested that it is visible. How can test that clicking outside of the menu will close the dropdown? as far as i know you can only call a .click() on a clickable element else it will throw an error.

```
it('Clicking on away from the dropdown menu should close the menu', () => {
    cy.get('???????').click()
    cy.get('#menu').should('not.be.visible')
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your dropdown really listens to `blur`. In that case you can do either:

```js
cy.get('#menu').blur()
```

or

```js
cy.get('body').focus()
```